# How can I scan an object with `${}`

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, frontend

How can I scan an array of object with `${}`?

For example, I have an array of object and i want to access with `${}` but it print only the first element. How can i scan with this notation?

```js
if (this.getProperty("sgaugeTooltip") && this.getProperty("sgaugeTooltip") != "") {
  console.log("sgaugeTooltip ", this.getProperty("sgaugeTooltip"));

  //${country}: ${value:number:0.00}                
  console.log("id", k, solidData[k].text);
  bandsArray[(2 * k) + 1].balloonText = this.getProperty("sgaugeTooltip") + " " + numeral(solidData[k][valueProperty] * 100).format(owner.getProperty("sgaugeFormat") || owner.getConfigTemplate("sgaugeFormat").default) + "%";

} else {
  //se è vuoto disegna solo le % nei baloon text
  bandsArray[(2 * k) + 1].balloonText = numeral(solidData[k][valueProperty] * 100).format(owner.getProperty("sgaugeFormat") || owner.getConfigTemplate("sgaugeFormat").default) + "%";
}
```

I have to put `${country}` for example inside the balloon text but it print only the first value

Comment: Can you explain the problem a little more clearly? It's hard to understand what you're asking, what the issue is, and how the code is related to any of it.

Comment: Can you show me all of the methos for access to an object in JS?

Comment: Please, provide more context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question and code example are not really easy to understand. That said, to access and print properties and values of an object with the ${} trick you could start by following the example below.

Let's say we have this js object:

```
tooltip = { 'text': 'Tooltip text' };
```

and this HTML object:

```
<div id="ballon"></div>
```

We can show the text of the tooltip object inside the #ballon div like this:

```
jQuery( '#ballon' ).html( `${tooltip.text}` );
```

Note the use of the backticks (`).

If you need to scan within an object like this one:

```
tooltips = {
  'tooltip1': 'text1',
  'tooltip2': 'text2',
  'tooltip3': 'text3',
}
```

you could do like this:

```
for (const tooltip_key in tooltips ) {
  console.log(`${tooltip_key}: ${tooltips[tooltip_key]}`);
}
```

expecting to have something like this in the console:

```
tooltip1: text1
tooltip2: text2
tooltip3: text3
```

Here I've tried just to guess, hope I got the point, but it would help more to others if you could be more precise about the question.